# Why does glAttachShader give a 1282 error?

Tags: opengl, haskell

I am running the following OpenGLRaw / Haskell code. The line `glAttachShader program vShader` generates a 1282 error. I am running the latest Mac OS X (which I believe is running OpenGL 4.1).

```
 let points = [0.0, 0.0, (0.0 :: GLdouble)]
      numPoints = (fromIntegral $ (length points) `div` 3)
  verticesPtr <- newArray points

  -- Buffer object to hold the vertices.                                                                                                                                             
  bufferPtr <- malloc :: IO (Ptr GLuint)
  glGenBuffers 1 bufferPtr
  bufferId <- peek bufferPtr
  glBindBuffer gl_ARRAY_BUFFER bufferId
  glBufferData gl_ARRAY_BUFFER
    (fromIntegral ((sizeOf (1.0 :: GLdouble)) * (length points)))
    verticesPtr gl_STATIC_DRAW

  -- Shaders                                                                                                                                                                         
  program <- glCreateProgram
  bindAttribLocation program 0 "position"

  vShader <- glCreateShader gl_VERTEX_SHADER
  vSource <- readFile "shaders/test.vert"                                                                                                                                            
  loadShaderSource vShader vSource                                                                                                                                                   
  glCompileShader vShader                                                                                                                                                            
  glAttachShader program vShader         

  glLinkProgram program
  glUseProgram program
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
#version 410 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Is it really the attach shader call that is generating the error? You are not using a fragment shader, so your state is invalid for drawing (transform feedback might work, though). Also, please check that you actually have a >=4.1 profile. You will get a <= 2.1 context when you use compatibility/old contexts. You have to specifically request a forward compatible >= 3.2 core context on OSX to get modern GL. Even if recent OSX in principle supports 4.1, it still depends on the GPU used if that version is available.

Comment: Note on the error code and all other enumeration constants. I think it is preferable to write them in hexadecimal notation, that is at least how they are commonly represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1282 (or 0x0502) is the enumeration constant for `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. I don't know where it is triggered though some recommendations on catching it.

- (If you not have already done so) Debug it by littering it with calls to `glGetError` and printing it. This helps in finding the exact location where the error was raised.
- Check the `glGetShaderInfoLog` for possible compilation errors of the shader.
- Check that you are really using OpenGL 4.1 and if possible the profile. Other versions or profiles of OpenGL might not allow some operations that are allowed in 4.1.

Comment: Thank you - your advice to check `glGetShaderInfoLog` helped me fix a bunch of compilation issues.